Drawing rooms for heatmap
Well I work on a bit complicated software where pretty much I have picture of layout/schematic of the building and while creating that I need to draw out a room/space that will later represent heat map of visitors.
Is there some UX solutions out there of people doing drawing out rooms with connecting lines/boxes etc ? Best scenario that I could find is this old way from google maps https://youtu.be/WX5gdxMKfgI?t=40
